# Send formated (bold, html, ...) Email to Gmail with PHP

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I am sending an e-mail with PHP to a gmail account.

```
$message = 
"Hi Mario

Today Luigi tried to <b>eat</b> <span style="font-size:8px">Toad</span>. 
I am so sorry that formating gmail is not standard. This mail will display the breaks made,
like in heredoc, but not the html. Help me understanding to format E-mails for 
Gmail-receivers.

It's a me
Greetings, 
Wario";

mail("mario@gmail.com", "Betreff: Luigi nibbled Toad",
$message, "From: itsame@myphpmail.com" );
```

How could we format that Gmail receivers see preformated text like font-size/weight/etc... ?

Comment: Look at this example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3348

Comment: You could also use a library like phpmailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com

Comment: @sammitch hi, thx. is it possible to send emails for gmail-only without html but the google intern format. I would prefer this because some people don't display html-emails and i only would like to make use of font-size and font-weight. btw, i tried that example before and it stripped all html for gmail.

Comment: @Frank thx but obviously (ressources) i don't intend to integrate a library for such a simple task.

Comment: SwiftMailer is a nice lib for that, too. You can send the text-only version of the message along with a HTML formatted one. More info: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html (don't know about the gmail specific markup, sorry)

Comment: Yeah... either `if(isGmail()) { send_plaintext(); }` or send a multipart email with both plaintext and HTML. Seriously, you should use PHPmailer or SwiftMailer because A) They do everything for you. B) They do it properly and abide by RFC standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the headers of the message to be formatted in HTML. Add this before your call to `mail()`.

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Itsame <itsame@myphpmail.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Than try sending it with the following:

```
mail("mario@gmail.com","Betreff: Luigi nibbled Toad", $message, $headers);
```

Comment: it strippes all html. unfortunately its not working at gmail.

Comment: @email if it's not working at Gmail that means you're doing it wrong. Make sure you're using *valid* html, that means using `<html><body></body></html>` which are missing from your code.